# Delphi, Windows 10, how to draw onto the "foreground" window?

Tags: delphi

I used to do it with that and worked fine on Windows XP:

```
 var
  WND : HWND;
  DC : HDC;
  FF : HFONT;

 begin
   FF:= CreateFont (12,0, GM_COMPATIBLE, 0, 12, dword(false),dword(false),dword(false), ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, pchar('Times New Roman'));

   WND:= GetForegroundWindow;
   DC:= GetDC(WND);
   SelectObject(DC, FF);
   TextOut (DC, 0,Y, pchar('test'), 4);
   ReleaseDC (WND, DC);
```

it sometimes still works, for example draws onto the application's own window, or onto Delphi7 itself, but for example not working on Firefox. How to do it bulletproofly on **Windows 10**?

Comment: This is something you cannot do "bulletproofly". (It wasn't a bulletproof approach in Windows XP, either. Actually, it has never been a bulletproof approach!) Having said that, you can create a semi-transparent window of your own which you put above the window you want to simulate drawing to.

Comment: You can't. It's not yours. Draw on your own windows. Probably the solution to your problem doesn't involve drawing over the top of a window outside of your control. But we don't know what your problem is. Perhaps you need to write a plug in or addin for Firefox.

Comment: Firefox was just an example. Simply, after a upgrading to Windows 10 it doesnt work what used to work on Windows XP

Comment: It can never have robustly worked. What is the problem your are working on. What is your goal.

Comment: of course not, yes. With XP it was flickering so that writing operation was timed, for 1 milliseconds. So it was flickering BUT working! The real aim is to show something durin a full screen game

Comment: hmmm, if I set the game to be OpenGL it seems to work

Comment: In order to show something over the game screen you should be using screen overlay surface and not rely on Windows GDI. Of course setting up screen overlay surface is a but more complicated as it requires you to create proper screen overlay surface that matches the graphical API the game is using (DirectX overlay surface for a DirectX game or OpenGL overlays surface for OpenGL based game). And even then there is no guarantee you could be successful. ...

Comment: ... If the game graphical engine is not developed to support overlays surfaces trying to forcefully include one into game rendering pipeline would probably crash the game rendering pipeline and thus the game itself. This is the reason why many older games that are on Steam still does not support using of Steam overlay windows or Steam overlay messages.